# Approval History (sObject 'ProcessInstance') - Overall Status field, queryable?

Tags: apex

1. Is it possible to declaratively capture the current 'Overall Status'
   from the Approval History object on the related master record? I
   assume that this is not possible.
2. Is it possible to SOQL on the the 'Overall Status' field from the
   Approval History? I am not able to find this field via the API
   (workbench). Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm), there is no field
   for 'Overall Status'.
3. If it is not possible to SOQL on the 'Overall Status' field, is the
   best approach to use a custom Visualforce page to override the
   standard page and use JavaScript to capture the first index in the
   'Overall Status' column? This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113111/nhelp-how-to-change-overall-status-text-approved-pending-rejected) looks like it would point
   me in the right direction. Or would another approach be to query all the ProcessInstanceSteps that belong to a single ProcessInstance record and query the StepStatus?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the `Status` field. You can also get the individual step statuses from `ProcessInstanceStep`.

```
SELECT Status, TargetObjectId, (Select StepStatus FROM Steps)
FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId = '<id_here>'
```